Contradiction in probability change of variables?
While doing some calculations I ran into a simple yet seemingly bizarre contradiction. Assume we have PDFs $p_x,p_y$ s.t. $x\sim N(0,1), y\sim N(1,1)$. Thus, for $f(x)=x-1$ we have that $p_x(f(x))=p_y(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}}$. However, from the change of variables formula - $p_x(f(x))=p_x(x)|{{f^{-1}}'(x)}|$ - we have that $p_x(x)=p_x(f(x))$, which is clearly false.
Where's the wrong step?

The problem is in your notation. For the change of variable $Y=g(X)$ in probability functions, one has:
$$
p_{Y}(y) = p_{X}(g^{-1}(y))|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)|
$$
If we were to apply the change as $g(x)=y=x+1$, we’d get:
$$
p_{Y}(y) = p_{X}(y-1),
$$
which is exactly what you need.

Thanks! It's technically notation but I think it's more subtle than that. It's that when we're doing a change of variables we're always going from one PDF to a different one, and not staying with the same one. Explicitly, the line $p_x(f(x))=p_x(x)|{f^{−1}}′(x)|$ is the wrong one.
